# Windows 8 Metro And Retro Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have start developing for windows 8 metro apps and I have one strange question for all of you.

Suppose I am having windows 8 pro edition with metro view and desktop(retro view) is also available. If I created metro style app it should be available to just metro view or retro view too. Or there is some way of switching one app in metro and retro view. Like My app is opened in metro view and I switched to retro view should I can access my app here as well with retro view as its opened in metro view and we all know app is designed for metro not retro but any way to access the app in both view but can switch UI according to current view.

Comment: Omg "retro" is an awesome name!

Comment: @Mehrdad +1, prefer "Desktop" to "Retro"

Comment: I love Retro as a word, but not when used to speak about Windows 7. Retro means that its design is imitative of the recent _past_. But, Windows 7 belongs here - _now_. Windows 8 is a stupid person's bad joke.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any way to do that. Metro/Desktop are 100% incompatible, because Metro apps are sandoxed.

The philosophy of Windows 8 is to have Metro apps. Desktop view is present essentially for reto-compatibility purpose. But in fact only WinRT components are incompatible (the graphic part), the .NET 4.5 part is -for the most important part- compatible.

Metro Style apps is full screen experience, so it doesn't make sense in a desktop environment. But tools can help you to write the two applications easily, like "portable class library" (PCL)